# neo4j pass parameter to variable length relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I use parameters with variable length relationships?

`MATCH path=(:Person {id: {id}})=[:HAS_FRIEND*0..{num_friends}]->(:Person)`

I'm trying to create a generic query so that I can pass a value 'num_friends' into the cypher query for various levels of relationships that I need.

I get an error so I'm wondering how something like this would be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can not be used as hops count.

But you can use [`path expander`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_path_expander) from [`apoc`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures):

```
match (P:Person {id: {id}}) with P
call apoc.path.expand( P, 'HAS_FRIEND>', 'Person', 0, {num_friends}) yield path
return path
```

Adapted for comment:

```
match (P:Person {id: {id}}) with P
call apoc.path.expand( P, 'HAS_FRIEND>', 'Person', 0, {num_friends}) yield path
with path, last(nodes(path)) as lst where not (lst)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(:Person)
return path
```

Comment: Looks like my example wasn't a good one. I'm actually searching a sequence, not friends of friends. So I actually just need the longest path found, not a list of all the paths. Adapting that to my current example, normally I have a `WHERE NOT (last:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(:Person)` after my `MATCH` statement. Is there a way your example can provide only the longest sequence found?

Comment: @TerenceChow You can add `where` after path expander.

Comment: I don't think your edit works because it returns 0 results. I guess the `last(nodes(path))` implicitly has no relationships after it has been returned? In any case I solved my problem with the following query if anyone looks for it in the future:

`WITH collect(nodes(path)) AS paths, MAX(length(path)) AS maxLength
  WITH FILTER(path IN paths WHERE length(path)= maxLength)[0] as longest`